# PYthon - Building 3rd layer of list within a hashmap

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key

I am currently on ex 39 of Learn Python the Hard way: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html

I am really stuck at the moment with this code, I am trying to add a 'third layer' of 'buckets' to the code so every individual key has its own dictionary, so that keys can hold multiple values.

There is too much code so I can't paste it all out here, but if you click on the link and scroll down you will see a subheading called: "Three Levels of Lists" and the last sentence/third paragraph under that subheading reads:

"If you want to take this code further, then change it to support multiple values for each key."

I've been trying to do this for around two days, and it is starting to get to me now. I just can't see a way to do it.

If anyone could please give me some guidance, I would appreciate it.

After implementing the code, I am getting this error:

```
File "ex39_test.py", line 34, in <module>
print "Michigan has: %s" % hashmap2.get(cities, hashmap2.get(states,     'Michigan'))
File "C:\python27\hashmap2.py", line 27, in get
i, k, vlist = get_slot(aMap, key, default=default)
File "C:\python27\hashmap2.py", line 18, in get_slot
bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
File "C:\python27\hashmap2.py", line 13, in get_bucket
bucket_id = hash_key(aMap, key)
File "C:\python27\hashmap2.py", line 10, in hash_key
```

After implementing this section of your code suggestion:

```
def set(aMap, key, value):
bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
i, k, vlist = get_slot(aMap, key)

if i >= 0:
    # if value is already in the key-list
    if value in vlist:
        return
    vlist.append(value)
else:
    bucket.append((key, list(value)))
```

I turned the 'key' variable into a mutable item - it is now in a list as a value as well as the key to its own list.

So now I Cannot hash it in my previous hash function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that, by adding a 3rd level, they are saying that rather than have a value for each key, you should have a list.

So we change set:

```
def set(aMap, key, value):
"""Sets the key to the value, only adds new values"""
  bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
  i, k, vlist = get_slot(aMap, key)
  if i >= 0:
      # check if value is already in list, if so, do nothing
      if value in vlist:
            return
      # the key exists, so just add they value to it
      vlist.append(value)
  else:
      # the key is not in table, add a list for the key
      # allows multiple values for each key
      bucket.append((key, list(value)))
```

I believe other functions remain unmodified.  Note that get() will return a list, not a single value.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. Do you know where I can find some instruction text online about assigning a list to a specific value (i.e. 'vlist') online? I'd like to do some reading around this concept and learn about it. It doesn't seem to be in Learn Python The Hard Way. 

I don't know what to google for to find the instruction/texts around the concept to learn about it.

Comment: I am not sure of your level, but there are lots of online python tutorials.  For example  https://developers.google.com/edu/python/   This wiki page has a large list https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers

Comment: I am having a new problem now after implementing your solution, and have edited my original answer to highlight it

Answer (score 1):

I also try to build a 3rd layer in the hash map, and I made it ,this is what my codes achieve.

[Because type 'list' is not hashable,so let's keep the 'key' type still 'string',and made 'value' type list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZxiQ.png)
Ps: I'm a student from China so please excuse my weird English expression.just want to be helpful!

This is the key part of my code:

```
def set(aMap, key, value):
'''Sets the key to the value, replacing an existing value.'''
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
    i, k, vlist = get_slot(aMap, key)

    if i >= 0:
    # the key exists, append it
        vlist.append(value)
    else:
    # the key does not, append to creat it
        bucket.append((key,[value])) 
    # attention! the key is string and value becomes list,which is the 3rd layer of bucket.
```

other function also need some according changes.

And,Notice this statement in ex39_test.py :

```
    print "Michigan has: %s" % hashmap.get(cities, hashmap.get(states, 'Michigan'))
```

In the above statement,when we call the hashmap.get function the first time, it will return a value but the value's type expects to be list, and it becomes the second parameter in the hashmap.get function when we call it once again!
And if you miss noticing it , the computer will hash this key in, of which type is list, and it will cause an unhashable mistake.

This is how I fix it in the hashmap.py:

```
def get(aMap, key , default = None):
'''Gets the value in a bucket for the given key, or the default.'''
    if type(key) == type (' ') :
    # if key's type is string,then nothing changes.
        i, k, vlist = get_slot(aMap, key, default)
    else: 
        i, k, vlist = get_slot(aMap, key[0], default) 
# in this way the second parameter is string again and it won't cause unhashable mistake.
    return vlist
```